# Centering Bootstrap input fields

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am new with this, especially with Bootstrap. I have this code:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-3">
       <div class="input-group">
         <input type="text" class="form-control">
         <span class="input-group-btn">
             <button class="btn btn-default" type="button">Go!</button>
         </span>
       </div><!-- /input-group -->
    </div><!-- /.col-lg-6 -->
</div><!-- /.row -->
```

I need to put this input field and button in the center of the page:

This didn't work: `"margin-left: auto; margin-right:auto;"`

[image: On webpage it looks like this]

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: use container class of bootstrap.

Comment: For Bootstrap use justify-content-center.

Answer (score 122, accepted):

You can use offsets to make a column appear centered, just use an offset equal to half of the remaining size of the row, in your case I would suggest using `col-lg-4` with `col-lg-offset-4`, that's `(12-4)/2`.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-lg-offset-4">
        <div class="input-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" /> 
            <span class="input-group-btn">
                <button class="btn btn-default" type="button">Go!</button>
            </span>
        </div><!-- /input-group -->
    </div><!-- /.col-lg-4 -->
</div><!-- /.row -->
```

**[Demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/koala_dev/akVd3/show)**

Note that this technique only works for even column sizes (`.col-X-2`, `.col-X-4`, `col-X-6`, etc...), if you want to support any size you can use `margin: 0 auto;` but you need to remove the float from the element too, I recommend a custom CSS class like the following:

```
.col-centered{
    margin: 0 auto;
    float: none;
}
```

**[Demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/koala_dev/akVd3/1/show)**

Comment: +1 The best solution, which the boostrap provides for solving the question's propose.

Comment: actually your solution based only on `col-lg-4 col-lg-offset-4` (also please fix the col-**lg**-offset-4). So in your solution you need to calculate manually the offset based on the `col-`-size. If it was calculated wrong the `text-center` will not help to center the element, so it is useless here as I played with this in the `jsfiddle`. waiting for feedback.

Comment: @static This was posted during the Release Candidate period of Bootstrap 3 and then there were no size distinction for offsets, so the fiddle was working with `col-offset-4`, I don't know why in my answer I did write `col-lg-offset-4` though, I remember there were some discrepancies between the documentation and the actual Bootstrap files back then, so it's possible I mixed them up.

Comment: @static I have updated my answer, I removed `text-center` because it wasn't serving any purpose since the only content here is a block element, I also added a better explanation of the offset approach and provided a new centering method that supports any column size.

Comment: Yes, I believe text-center property applies to inline elements within a block element.

Comment: Thank you for this, it works like a charm with ASP.NET Core!

Comment: In newer bootstrap versions there is no `col-lg-offset-[num]` it is changed with the simple `offset-lg-[num]`.

Comment: Thank you @Ivanp for updating us on the new version format. it saved me.

Answer (score 12):

Using offsets is not desired for responsive websites.

Use a flexbox with justify content center:

```
<div class="row d-flex justify-content-center">
  <input></input>
</div>
```

Comment: This worked for me with Bootstrap  5.0. I applied it to the `<div class="form-group">...</div>` where my input was. Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

Try applying this style to your `div class="input-group"`:

```
text-align:center;
```

View it: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gsubiran/yNZQV/).

Answer (score 10):

The best way for centering your element it is using `.center-block` helper class. But must your bootstrap version not less than **3.1.1**

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-3 center-block">
    <div class="input-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control">
      <span class="input-group-btn">
             <button class="btn btn-default" type="button">Go!</button>
         </span>
    </div>
    <!-- /input-group -->
  </div>
  <!-- /.col-lg-6 -->
</div>
<!-- /.row -->
```

Answer (score 5):

Ok, this is best solution for me. Bootstrap includes mobile-first fluid grid system that appropriately scales up to 12 columns as the device or viewport size increases. So this worked perfectly on every browser and device:

```
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-4"></div>
            <div class="col-lg-4">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" /> 
                    <span class="input-group-btn">
                        <button class="btn btn-default" type="button">Go!</button>
                    </span>
                </div><!-- /input-group -->
            </div><!-- /.col-lg-4 -->
            <div class="col-lg-4"></div>
        </div><!-- /.row -->
```

It means 4 + 4 + 4 =12... so second div will be in the middle that way.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/jpGwm/embedded/result/

Comment: You don't need the empty `<div>` tags, avoid the need of extra markup by using offset as I showed in my answer

Comment: Just keep the middle div, like this: <div class="col-lg-4 col-lg-offset-4">....</div> Offset basically adds that empty div that you wrote....without having to write it

Answer (score 4):

For me this solution worked well to center an input field in a TD:

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<td style="background:#B3AEB5;">
  <div class="form-group text-center">
    <div class="input-group" style="margin:auto;">
      <input type="month" name="p2" value="test">
    </div>
  </div>
</td>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to use this code:

```
.col-lg-3 {
  width: 100%;
}
.input-group {
   width: 200px; // for exemple
   margin: 0 auto;
}
```

if it didn't work use !important

Comment: The whole point of bootstrap though is that .col-lg-3 takes up 3 columns. Changing the width to 100% breaks the whole thing.

Answer (score 1):

Well in my case the following work fine

```
<div class="card-body p-2">
  <div class="d-flex flex-row justify-content-center">
     <div style="margin: auto;">
        <input type="text" autocomplete="off"
          style="max-width:150px!important; "
          class="form-control form-control-sm font-weight-bold align-self-center w-25" id="dtTechState">
     </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

For bootstrap 4 use offset-4, see below.

```
<div class="mx-auto">        
        <form class="mx-auto" action="/campgrounds" method="POST">
            <div class="form-group row">                
                <div class="col-sm-4 offset-4">
                    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="name" placeholder="name">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group row">               
                <div class="col-sm-4 offset-4">
                    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="picture" placeholder="image url">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group row">
                    <div class="col-sm-4 offset-4">
                        <input class="form-control" type="text" name="description" placeholder="description">
                    </div>
                </div>
            <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Submit!</button>
            <a class="btn btn-secondary"  href="/campgrounds">Go Back</a>
        </form>      
    </div>
```

Answer (score -1):

in b4 you can use **d-flex justify-content-center** too

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="form-group">
                
    <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
    
    <input type="text" class="form-control">
    
     <span class="input-group-btn">
         <button class="btn btn-default" type="button">Go!</button>
     </span>
     
    </div>      
        
</div>
```