# How to center the ".input-group-btn" in bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, centering

How to center the bootstrap `input-grop`?

Here is the `jsfiddle`: http://jsfiddle.net/Qs4T9/

I would like to make the `input-grpup` in the center of the row, but without manually calculating all that offsets. Would be better if it would be something like `.text-center`, `display: table`, `display: table-cell` or similar.

Here is an "answer" [ [Centering Bootstrap input fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18036315/centering-bootstrap-input-fields) ], but it's not a really centering, looks more like just a workaround for the concrete elements and the sizes, not a general solution (at least for the whole non-mobile scheme).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the class .col-xs-6 is set to float:left;

If you remove that and add:

```
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
```

instead, it should solve your problem!

Comment: nope, doesn't work (if I remove the `.col-xs-6` it becomes full-width (i.e. block)). could you edit the jsfiddle I posted?

Comment: I didn't say remove col-xs-6! Just remove the float value for it, but since col-xs-6 is built-in bootstrap css, you have to override it like so: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Qs4T9/2/)